# What are android SDK and Gradle path?

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk, gradle

I installed android sdk with terminal and it installed completely and now I need its path. There was no "android/sdk" folder in home. I searched and found sdk in `/usr/lib/android-sdk`. I also installed gradle but I can't find it. Where is it?(I need the path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed them via the package manager (`apt`, `apt-get`, `dpkg`), you can ask the packaging system where the files in a package are with `dpkg -L <packagename>` (read `man dpkg`).